# Python selenium webdriver time exception when using wait until

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, wait

Website form select is disabled until the previous form has been completed.It takes some time for website to recognize the fill out. I try to use `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "...")))`, but it returns me a time exception error. I tried sleep(2), and it works. I am wondering if I can still use wait in this case.

Comment: You should specify how much time you want to wait until expected condition. In answer provided by KevGeo `(driver, 30)` means that your script will wait 30 seconds for required element and raise `TimeOutException` if it still not clickable

Answer (score 1):

You question isn't clear. You should show what you have tried/accomplished so far in detail. However, from what I understand I will try to answer you question in general.

To wait for an element to be clickable the correct syntax would be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ID_of_the_element")));
element.click();
```

In this case I have used ID as the element locator. You can use others such as XPATH as well.

Hope the helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for my confuse text. I used wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10), and it returns me a time exception error. I assume 10 here is 10 secs. I am wondering whether the form(select option) is not clickable.

Comment: The select option is clickable, however you need do it using the right method. This is how I would click on a select option:
`labels = [list of required/desirable options/a single option];
element = driver.find_element_by_id(element_id);
for option in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
     if option.text in labels:
           option.click();`
Do let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: @YingheChen Please let me know if the above code snippet is difficult to understand, I would be glad to add it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks kev, I still have trouble clicking on the button. I think this might be caused by two things. One is that the current button is outside of browser screen, and I need to scroll down a little bit to see the button. I have tried to scroll down but still not work. Second is that this website is using ng-click, which I am not familiar with. Here is a screen shot of the code. http://workforothers.com/Yinghe/code.png  Thank you again for your help.